# ASP.NET listbox selectedValue in PageLoad

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, postback, pageload

I have a problem with listbox. I would like to fill it with data and select Value (`listbox.SelctedValue`), using postback, after  textbox is filled and `Page.Validate()` is fired.  I try to use it in Page_Load. Everything works fine until I dont mark another user. It goes back to the the first one. I know its because I mark the first one again and again it in Page_Load, but how can I mark user after postback in other place? I cant use any buttons.

To be more clear, I have one text box, which causes postback after user put text there. After that I would like to check if `Page.Isvalid` and is yes, add that user to listbox (which also causes postbacks) and mark him. Without any buttons. How can I do it only once, using autopostback, not every PageLoad ?

Comment: paste code what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            //Mylistbox.SelctedValue = set Your Selected Value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But this will be fired only at the first page load. I would like to fire it after the textBox is filled, so in PostBack.

Comment: I see u have edited post. But now it will be fired EVERY postback, so , when i choose something on the listbox, which also causes postbacks, selction will go back to first one. This code is exactly what I had and that was my problem...